# BIRT - Printable Table Of content - Displaying Issue

Tags: pdf, birt, tableofcontents, actuate

Good Morning Gentleman,

I am a Tunisian Software Engineer,
During my summer internship I was asked to use BIRT (Business Intelligence and reporting tool) in order to create a Report/pdfDocument with a displayed TOC (table of content) on the first page ..

As More explanation, i am trying to find a solution to create a report that looks like it's been created by Microsoft word (Exported as PDF).

Briefly, I tried to use existent design pages such as "printable TOC.rptdesign" and other samples, the TOC was created successfully on the left of the generated report **BUT** This result doesn't fullfill our needs because i want it to be displayed on the first page ..

Question : BIRT is it able to create an automatic printable TOC, that can be displayed dynamically on the first page of the document/report?

I will be grateful,
Cordially

Comment: I am facing the same problem and having the same question. I need to display the whole TOC at the beginning of my report.  I know that after indexing the different sections/titles of my document, I am able to display them in the BIRT Report viewer or any pdf viewer, but I need it printable and part of my report itself.